# Significance of writelimit in BodyContentHandler of apache tika api?

Tags: java, apache-tika

In our application we are supposed to check if a file (any format) is password protected or not,
For that purpose we are using Apache Tika API.
The code piece would look something like below.

```
public static boolean isPasswordProtectedFile(File filePart) {
    Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    ParseContext context = new ParseContext();

    try {
        // parsing the file and testing for Password
        parser.parse(FileUtils.openInputStream(filePart), handler, metadata, context);
        LOGGER.debug("File is without Password ");
    } catch (EncryptedDocumentException e) {
        LOGGER.error("File is encrypted with password", e);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("File parsing failed", e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

But this is consuming too much of the CPU for few files we tested. But if we create BodyContentHandler like below. then it completes faster and uses less CPU.
`BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);`

I went through the documentation but couldn't understand it correctly. Looking forward for a probable reason for that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the document, it says

https://tika.apache.org/1.4/api/org/apache/tika/sax/BodyContentHandler.html#BodyContentHandler(int)

> Creates a content handler that writes XHTML body character events to an internal string buffer. The contents of the buffer can be retrieved using the ContentHandlerDecorator.toString() method.
> The internal string buffer is bounded at the given number of characters. If this write limit is reached, then a SAXException is thrown.

> writeLimit - maximum number of characters to include in the string, or -1 to disable the write limit

Buffer is never initialized here.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your time. But,  I am trying to understand what would be the side effects of disabling the write limit?

Comment: When you will try to read content you might get `SAXException`

Comment: For one you could get out of memory error for a very large document